# Missing username error on authentication for register node/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, passport.js

I'm following some tutorial on express for authentication with passport and jwt, then I got this error after creating route for user registration

[image]

I pass my authentication to middleware like this,

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import expressJwt from "express-jwt";

const TOKEN_TIME = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; // 30days
const SECRET = "The 3arth sucks in h3r3";

let authenticate = expressJwt({ secret: SECRET });
let generateAccessToken = (req, res, next) => {
  req.token = req.token || {};
  req.token = jwt.sign(
    {
      id: req.user.id
    },
    SECRET,
    {
      expiresIn: TOKEN_TIME
    }
  );
  next();
};

let respond = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    user: req.user.username,
    token: req.token
  });
};

module.exports = { respond, authenticate, generateAccessToken};
```

then in my controller, I did route for register

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { Router } from "express";
import passport from "passport";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

import config from "../config";
import User from "../models/user";

import {
  generateAccessToken,
  respond,
  authenticate
} from "../middleware/authMiddleware";

export default ({ config, db }) => {
  let api = Router();

  api.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    User.register(
      new User({
        email: req.body.email
      }),
      req.body.password,
      (err, user) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(user);

        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        }
        passport.authenticate("local", {
          session: false
        })(req, res, () => {
          res.status(200).send("Successfully created new user");
        });
      }
    );
  });

  return api;
};
```

and in my root file

```
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import passport from "passport";
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

import config from "./config";
import routes from "./routes";

let app = express();
app.server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    limit: config.bodyLimit
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
const User = require("./models/user");
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password"
    },
    User.authenticate()
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use("/v1", routes);

app.server.listen(config.port);
console.log(`Started on port ${app.server.address().port}`);

export default app;
```

and in my model I have this,

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import passportLocalMongoose from "passport-local-mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String
    // unique: true
    // required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String
    // required: true
  }
});

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User);
```

I have latest installed passport, express v.4.16.4
I try to test on postman with urlencoded for header and also tried application/json but neither of them succeed
Why am I getting this error? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller code change the parameter of register middleware from email to username.that might do the trick